# Using Evothings JavaScript to read BLE characteristic data

Tags: bluetooth

I have a BLE (Bluetooth 4.0)pedometer device from which I want to read the characteristic data using Evothings plugin (which uses Javascript API to interact with the device)

I am using following code -
callback when device is connected =

```
function deviceConnected(device) {
    console.log('Connected to device: ' + device.name)
    console.log('Reading services... Have patience!')
    device.readServices(
        null, // null means "read all services".
         readAllServicesCharacteristicsAndNotifications,
        // listAllServicesCharacteristicsDescriptors,
        readServicesError)
}
```

callback code for readAllServicesCharacteristicsAndNotifications -

```
function readAllServicesCharacteristicsAndNotifications(device) {
    // Get data for each service
   console.log('number of services ' + device.__services.length)
   console.log('number of characteristic ' + device.__services[0].__characteristics.length)
        //var characteristic = service.__characteristics[characteristicUUID]
        device.readCharacteristic(
        device.__services[0].__characteristics[8]['uuid'],
        function (data) {
            var test = new Uint8Array(data);
            var result = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
                console.log('data  element is ' + test[i]);
                console.log('data  element string is ' + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(test[i], 2)));
                result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(test[i], 2));
            }

            console.log('data  is ' + result);
        },
        function (errorCode) {
        console.log('BLE readCharacteristic error: ' + errorCode);
     });
}
```

I think BLE data formatsuggests that data is exchanged as binary code bytes.
I see the value in the byte array but I don't know how to interpret it.

Has anyone used Evothings Javascript to interact with BLE device?

Answer (score 0):

H i, the data received in JavaScript over BLE is a byte buffer.

See if you can find the documentation for the pedometer. Lookup at the format of the data sent from the pedometer. Then access the data in the buffer accordingly.

Here are some examples.

Access byte values in the data buffer:

```
var buf = new Uint8Array(data);
var value1 = buf[0];
var value2 = buf[1];
```

To get a 16-bit value use bitwise OR, for example:

```
var value = buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8);
```

Depending on data being little endian or big endian, the bitwise OR needs to be done in different ways.

Here is a library you can use that has functions for accessing values in a byte buffer: https://github.com/evothings/evothings-examples/blob/master/resources/libs/evothings/util/util.js

Here is an example:

```
// Get the signed int value in the buffer thats starts at
// byte index 2 (the int value represented by byte 2 and 3).
var value = evothings.util.littleEndianToInt16(data, 2)
```

Hope this helps!